# Decrypting AES GCM 256 with pgcrypto (PostgresQL)

Tags: postgresql, encryption, aes-gcm, pgcrypto

I am trying to decrypt a message with pgcrypto that is encrypted with AES GCM 256.

Specifications of the encryption:

```
Encryption algorithm     AES
Key                      [secret of listener] (64-character-long hexadecimal string in configuration)
Key length               256 bits (32 bytes)
Block mode               GCM
Padding                  None
Initialization vector    In HTTP header (X-Initialization-Vector)
Authentication tag       In HTTP header (X-Authentication-Tag)
```

So I receive a:

- body
- key
- iv_header
- auth_tag

I tried the below

```
with base as (
select
    'F8E2F759E528CB69375E51DB2AF9B53734E393' as body,
    '000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F' as key,
    '3D575574536D450F71AC76D8' as iv_header,
    '19FDD068C6F383C173D3A906F7BD1D83' as auth_tag
),
out as (
    select
        decrypt_iv(
            convert_to(concat(decode(body,'hex'),decode(auth_tag,'hex')),'LATIN1'),
            decode(key, 'hex'),
            decode(iv_header, 'hex'),
            'aes/pad:none'
        )
    from base
)

select * from out
```

I keep getting the error `decrypt_iv error: Data not a multiple of block size` while I would expect to get the encoded message `{"type": "PAYMENT"}`

I expect that something goes wrong in the decoding and concatenating of `body` and `auth_tag`, but can't figure out what.

Some notes on what/why I did that

- I concat the `auth_tag` to the `body` as several sources describe it that way.
- I use the `convert_to` function as it seems the only way to concatenate two `bytea` values

I manage to decrypt this message in other languages (i.e. Snowflake or Python)

If anyone sees what I am doing wrong or has some directions it is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the code that does it in python?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, a sample for different languages can be found here https://peachpayments.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/webhooks/decryption-example
My feeling is that the Scala sample can be helpful as it also appends the auth_tag to the encrypted body. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgcrypto only says it supports cbc and ecb.  I'm not a cryptographer, but I don't think either of those is the same thing as GCM.  So I don't think you can do this with pgcrypto.  I don't know why it leads to the exact error you get, but it also doesn't surprise me.

If I really needed to do this inside the database, I think I do it by writing a function using `pl/python3u`.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, that makes sense, I hoped GCM would be a variant of of CBC/EBC. I think we'll just do the decryption outside of the database. Thanks, Chris